# Importing data into R with custom names

Tags: r, import, dataset, naming, file-rename

This is my first StackOverflow question so I apologize if anything is unclear!

I am trying to import data into R & change the name of each file (9 files in total), all named "Unit # (Chapter #) - User Attempts". I have everything in a loop right now that takes each file name and pulls out characters 1-6 and 27-50.

Ideally, I would like to rename each file "week2, week3, week4, week8, week9, week10, week11, week12, week13" rather than pulling from the existing title.

Here's the loop I have so far:

```
mydir = "C:/Users/Julia/Desktop/RWorkDirectory/2MC3 21-22/User Attempts"
temp = list.files(path=mydir,pattern="*.csv", full.names=FALSE)
names = paste0(substr(temp, 1,6), substr(temp, 27,50))
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(names[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Is there any way to change this so that I can assign a custom name to each file? Haven't found anything online that addresses this so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
mydir = "C:/Users/Julia/Desktop/RWorkDirectory/2MC3 21-22/User Attempts"
temp = list.files(path=mydir,pattern="*.csv", full.names=FALSE)
names = paste0(substr(temp, 1,6), substr(temp, 27,50))
custom_names <- c("week2", "week3", "week4", "week8", "week9", "week10", "week11", "week12", "week13")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(custom_names[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Comment: Amazing! I appreciate your help so much, take care :)